# Emmet in VS Code not correctly converting HTML links

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, emmet

When I select a plain text link in a HTML file and convert it using Emmet in VS Code by typing "a," a preview is shown as below:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com">https://www.google.com</a>
```

However, when I click Enter, the link in the href attribute disappears to become:

```
<a href="">https://www.google.com</a>
```

How can I prevent this from happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: which emmet command do you use? I use `Emmet: Wrap abbreviation` and nothing strange happens when I press Enter

Comment: Ah I have tried it with "Wrap individual lines with abbreviation" and it works, however, it didn't work with "Wrap with abbreviation"

Comment: I always use the `lines` version, I don't see a need for the single line, if it is not an URL selected the `lines` version behaves as you describe

Answer (score 0):

Using Emmet you can print `a:link` or just `a:link[href="https://www.google.com"]{https://www.google.com}`, however visit [Element types](https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/types/)